# Android Studio 4.2.1 Layout Inspector not working

Tags: android, android-studio, layout-inspector

I'm trying to start layout inspector when my app is running on emulator but when i select the process of the app, the app close and android studio display an error notification `Connection failed`

[image: layout inspector connection failed]

Comment: I don't know how to solve this.... in my experience, I find layout inspector an amazing tool WHEN it works. Problem is: it doesn't always work. It has been working in 4.2.1 but as soon as I upgraded to 4.2.2, yesterday, it stopped working (==it "connects" to the device but shows nothing...).